# Error NullReference exception for mvc model in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wrote this code in jQuery, but it shows error:

> null exception for model.

```
if (@Model != null) {
    if (@Model.BirthDate != null) {
      @{
          PersianDateTime pt = new PersianDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(Model.BirthDate));
       }
       $("#BirthDate").val(@pt.Year + "/" + @pt.Month + "/" + @pt.Day);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `@model` is going to render as `Model path`. you need to add a property to check null for model

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Please explain more

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:

***Model class***

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId {get;set;}
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
        public string Email {get;set;}

        public bool Empty
        {
            get { return (CustomerId == 0 && 
                          string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) &&
                          string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName) &&
                          string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email));
                }
        }
    }
```

***View File***

```
@model MyProj.Customer
if (@Model.Empty)
 {
 }
else
 {
 }
```

In your case, it rendered like this:

```
if(MyProj.Customer != null)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood.